# How to compile a project from github for composer but do not use composer repository?

Tags: github, composer-php, octobercms

I want to instal October CMS, installation guide is here: https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation
but I do not want use composer and install it from repository by composer.

I want download files from here: https://github.com/octobercms/october
and install/compile downloaded files on my local server.

Comment: You can't not use composer. Plugins (since v2) and OctoberCMS core modules depend on it. You will not be able to update dependencies. Why you do not want to use Composer?

Comment: @RajaKhoury I want use composer but for files on my local computer, that I downloaded by self I don't want use composer repository and create own.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

October is no longer free and open source (see https://octobercms.com/blog/post/october-cms-moves-become-paid-platform), and as a part of their v2 they no longer support hosts without composer support or `exec()` access. The best you could do with October is purchase a license, use composer locally; and then just transfer the files to your server directly, but you won't be able to use the backend to install or update the core, plugins, or themes from the marketplace.

The good news is that the core maintainers have forked the project and are continuing the original project as Winter CMS (see https://github.com/wintercms/winter/issues/5; disclaimer, I'm one of them); and Winter CMS will continue to supports hosts without composer or `exec()` access.

Winter CMS is currently only available to install through composer, but it does support installing and updating plugins via the backend without composer. We're currently hard at work at getting our marketplace up and running, as well as our web installer, but in the meantime it uses October's marketplace instead.